# Exporting table to Excel only works from development machine, not from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following piece of code to export tables to Excel but I just realized if I upload this to a server, it will not work. It will only work on the development machine.

```
function writeToExcel(tableID,columnas) 
{
  str="";

  var myTableHead = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = myTableHead.rows.length;

  var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
  var ExcelSheet = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
  ExcelSheet.Application.Visible = true;
  var celda = new Array(columnas);  
  //f = Nro Filas
  getN(tableID);
  for(f=0;f<n;f++){
    //g = Nro Columnas
    for(g=0;g<columnas;g++)
    {
        //if(g!=1 || g!= 8 || g!=10 || g!= 12){
        str= document.getElementById(tableID+f+""+g).innerHTML;
        ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Cells(f+1,g+1).value = str;

    }
  }
}
```

am I missing something?? In the dev machine it works wonderfully! but on the server side it doesn't. Is there a better way to do this? Maybe using jQuery?

I get an error on the server side saying:
`Automation server can't create object` and it gives me the error on the following line,

```
  var ExcelApp = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: have you installed excel on your server?

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui it's installed on the user's computer, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui elaborate more...

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not designed to run on the server. There are a number of ways to write out excel on the server using server side technology. PLease see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

In your case you could write the same html table to the response stream and set the mime type to `application/vnd.ms-excel`